# removing a countable subset from an infinite set doesn't change cardinality

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Prove that if an infinite set $S$ has a countable (infinite or finite) subset removed from it leaving the set $T$, and $T$ is infinite then:
$$|S|=|T|$$

I have seen some proofs related to this but usually only regarding removing a finite set.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I'm actually really new to this topic so I don't really even know what kind of things to try

Comment: It's the same thing thing and the same reason.  The thing is if $S$ is countably infinite removing a countable subset *might* result in a finite set, so it's usually not stated as such.

Comment: The point is that any infinite set has a countably infinite subset (and the union of two countable sets is countable). This uses the axiom of choice. Without this axiom, this fact may fail, and the result itself is consistently false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: let be $R$ the countably infinite subset s.t. $S = T\cup R$. Extract $Q\subset T$ countably infinite. Construct a bijection between $Q$ and $R\cup Q$.

Comment: Ok, I’ve constructed a bijection, but how does it help me?

Comment: @gonengazit, typo correction. And now you have the disjoint unions $S = (T\setminus Q)\cup Q\cup R$, $T =  (T\setminus Q)\cup Q$.

Answer (score 0):

If S is countable and T is infinite, then T must be countable.  If S is uncountably infinite, then removing a countable set leaves a noncountable set behind.

Comment: yes, but there are a lot of uncountable cardinalities. how do you prove that T and S have the same one?